# Presto : how to select on a table_name with special characters

Tags: presto, space, tablename, trino

How to make a select on a table containing special characters with presto on SQL Server.

For exemple :
  select * from myconnecter.[XXX, s_a_$item ledger entry];

My table name is [XXX, s_a_$item ledger entry] 
and I have this error:
   failed: line 1:28: mismatched input '.' expecting {, ',', 'ADD', 'AS', '

I already tried different solutions with \" or '' or removing brackets ... no idea...

Comment: Presto uses the SQL standard identifier escape character, double quote.  If you need a double quote in an identifier, you can escape a double quote with another double quote.

Answer (score 2):

Presto follows the SQL standard, which uses double quotes: `SELECT * FROM myconnecter."[XXX, s_a_$item ledger entry]"`

Comment: Your feedback is excellent ! what is strange it works but it seems I have an error on uppercase/lower case. The real name of the table is [XXXX, S_A_$Item Ledger Entry] and I have the error message : select * from navision.dbo."XXXX, S_A_$Item Ledger Entry";
Query 20190805_172741_00078_3c2fm failed: line 1:15: Table navision.dbo.sein, s_a_$item ledger entry does not exist
select * from navision.dbo."Sein, S_A_$Item Ledger Entry"

Comment: Try setting `case-insensitive-name-matching=true` for the connector configuration.