# Escape Greater Than for Column Name in Athena

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I would like to name the output of my columns with "<" greater or less than symbols.

```
Select worker_name as '<<Worker>>'
from employ
```

But I am getting

```
 mismatched input ''<<Worker>>''. Expecting: <identifier>
```

I have tried escaping with "`" and "ESCAPE" but no luck. Is there and way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column name with a Space - Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54203027/column-name-with-a-space-athena)

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363073/presto-how-to-select-on-a-table-name-with-special-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Double Quotes instead of Single Quotes seems to be the correct way

```
Select worker_name as "<<Worker>>"
from employ
```